# В Django 3.0.7 не загружаются изображения с шаблона, но загружаются из админки

Tags: python, html, django, веб-программирование

Код ниже. При загрузке фото по шаблону и при нажатии на кнопку Post, фото не загружается никуда, но если загрузить фото в пост из админки, то оно загрузится исправно. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Заранее спасибо!

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'value':'', 'id':'userid'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    body = models.TextField()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args = [str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, doument_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

add_post.html

```
  <form class = "form-group">
    <form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button formmethod="POST">Post</button>
```

Comment: опечатка в urls.py: doument_root?

Comment: @Jack_oS, опечатку исправил, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Откройте любую страницу  с картинками. Если они не отображаются в коде все равно есть адрес откуда должна грузиться картинка. Соответственно сравните путь с тем где они реально расположены. З.Ы. Попробуйте вместо STATICFILES_DIRS  прописать `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Comment: @Kers, существует директория media/images. Если нажать на кнопку Post не в админке, то картинка никуда не добавится, и при просмотре поста её не будет. Если же добавить изображение к посту из админки, то оно появится в директории media/images, и всё работает исправно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я исправил проблему, изменив данные шаблона:

```
  <div class = "form-group">
    <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type ="submit" formmethod="post">Post</button>
  </div>
```

Не знаю, что из добавленного точно нужно, но теперь всё работает.